A strange problem with C/C++ optimized(-O2) programs
Program A, with global variables x and y:
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

const int maxn = 3000000 + 10;
int dp[maxn], n, maxy;
int x, y;        // <-- Global variables `x` and `y`
vector<int> a[maxn];

int main() {
    freopen("demo.txt", "r", stdin);
    freopen("demo.out", "w", stdout);

    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        //int x, y;
        scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);
        a[y].push_back(x-1);
        maxy = max(maxy, y);
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= maxy; i++) {
        dp[i] = dp[i - 1];
        if (a[i].size() == 0) continue;
        for (int j = 0; j < a[i].size(); j++) {
            int u = a[i][j];
            dp[i] = max(dp[i], dp[u] + i - u);
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n", dp[maxy]);
    
    return 0;
}

Program B, almost the same with program A, but with local variables x and y (x and y can be considered as the two endpoints of an interval that $x < y$).
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

const int maxn = 3000000 + 10;
int dp[maxn], n, maxy;
//int x, y;
vector<int> a[maxn];

int main() {
    freopen("demo.txt", "r", stdin);
    freopen("demo2.out", "w", stdout);

    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        int x, y;         // <-- Local variables `x` and `y`
        scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);
        a[y].push_back(x-1);
        maxy = max(maxy, y);
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= maxy; i++) {
        dp[i] = dp[i - 1];
        if (a[i].size() == 0) continue;
        for (int j = 0; j < a[i].size(); j++) {
            int u = a[i][j];
            dp[i] = max(dp[i], dp[u] + i - u);
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n", dp[maxy]);
    
    return 0;
}

Compile instruction (with -O2 optimized):
g++ demo.cpp -o demo.exe -O2 -std=c++14

Compile information:
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=C:/mingw64/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
Thread model: posix
gcc version 8.1.0 (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project)

Those two programs get the different results with the same input!
With the same input data, I've watched the variables of x, y, maxy, a[i], and all of them got the same data. And the array element dp[i] got the different data. I don't know why, the variable dp[i] and x, y are unrelated!
And if I compile them without -O2 instruction, that is g++ demo.cpp -o demo.exe -std=c++14, they get the same output!
The big input data comes here: https://ww0.lanzouq.com/iesib26alt6f
It's a txt file, with about 150001 lines.
BTW:
This program is a solution to this question, However, you can ignore this information. The issue I've gotten seems to be no relation with that question.

Have you tried running it with a sanitizer, just to check for Undefined Behavior?

Are you sure that scanf actually succeeds? Since you're just ignoring its return value...

@AdrianJałoszewski which code is UB? Is it int j = 0? I've changed to vector<int>::size_type j = 0 and get the same issue.

Unfortunately, some of the links in your question are taking us to some chinese websites. And some of them even want us to log in to access what you want to share.

As a side note, please consider using more readable variable names than just a, n, u, dp  etc. - having several lines like dp[i] = max(dp[i], dp[u] + i - u);  makes the code hard to parse (at least for me)

If the first scanf("%d %d", &x, &y); fails, then your program has undefined behaviour, as you are using uninitialized variables. If y is ever less than 0 or greater than 3000009, then your program has undefined behaviour because you access a out of bounds. If x is ever less than 1 or greater than 3000010, then your program has undefined behavior because you access dp out of bounds.

d[0] was never initialized the on the first iteration of the second loop so that value it reads could be anything.

@user1139069 globals are always value initialized (by the standard), it will always contain 0, this is defined behavior by the standard.

Link to task requires registration. It is better to copy description of task into a question.

FYI, there is no language C/C++.  Your code is in C++ since the C language doesn't have std::vector.

your input file at line 3076 contains
0 437122

then in your code you are doing an out of bounds access when doing
a[y].push_back(x-1); // a[y][last] = -1
...
int u = a[i][j];
dp[i] = max(dp[i], dp[u] + i - u);  // dp[u] = dp[-1]

out of bounds access is undefined behavior, it just happened not to crash with -O0 and crashes with -O2, likely due to different layout of globals.
you could detect this bug with an assert.
assert(u >= 0 && u < maxn);

alternatively you can use std::array<int,maxn> dp; and hope your standard library has asserts on bracket operator in debug mode like MSVC does.

Because you start your loop through dp at 1, you subtract 1 from x, and any 0s you read in become -1, which are invalid indexes.
You can fix this by looping from 0. I have used std::vector::at when accessing an index for the first time because it is checked. Switching to std::vector also means things are appropriately sized.
N.b. it is much better to declare variables at the point you initialise them, or as soon before when reading from input.
int main() {
    freopen("demo.txt", "r", stdin);
    freopen("demo2.out", "w", stdout);

    int n, maxy = -1;
    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1) return 1;
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> a(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int x, y;
        if (std::scanf("%d %d", &x, &y) != 2) return 2;
        a.at(y).push_back(x);
        maxy = std::max(maxy, y);
    }
    std::vector<int> dp(maxy + 1);
    int prev = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= maxy; i++) {
        int& dpi = dp[i];
        dpi = prev;
        for (int u : a[i]) {
            dpi = std::max(dpi, dp.at(u) + i - u);
        }
        prev = dpi;
    }
    printf("%d\n", dp.back());
}

